# R plotly choropleth disable mouse wheel zoom

Tags: r, zooming, plotly, mousewheel, choropleth

I'm plotting a choropleth map using plotly package on R
https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/

But the mouse wheel zooming in/out is very annoying. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Something like this? https://plot.ly/javascript/disable-zoom/

Comment: Not exactly since for these kind of plot, there is no zooming with mousewheel in contrary to choropleth.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn scroll zoom off through 'scrollZoom' in Choropleth maps.

```
dcc.Graph(config = dict({'scrollZoom': False}))
```